# difference between topic/send_message_operation_count and topic/send_request_count in google pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

What is the difference between topic/send_message_operation_count and topic/send_request_count in google pubsub.

The requirement is though i can calculate no.of messages present in subscriber by undeliver_messages but I need to calculate how many messages are pushed to the topic.

Thanks,
Santosh

Comment: hey Santosh.a  I would like to know how did you calculate the number of messages in a subscription using this method. I have came across a similar issue getting an accurate count of messages.

Answer (score 8):

The docs for `topic/send_message_operation_count` say:

> Cumulative count of publish message operations, grouped by result.

The docs for `topic/send_request_count` say:

> Cumulative count of publish requests, grouped by result.

Pub/Sub allows multiple messages to be batched in a single API request. `send_request_count` is the number of publish API calls, while `send_message_operation_count` is the number of actual messages in those calls.

So if on average each request sends 10 messages, `send_message_operation_count` will be 10x `send_request_count`. If you publish one message per API call, they will be the same.